# Can we replace $ in prototype.js with some thing else like $p or $proto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am using jquery and prototype.js. There is conflict in $.It could be resolved by using var $j = jQuery.noConflict(), but i have a plenty of file that are using $ for jquery so that would not be easy to remove. even i am using some plugings that also needs to be rename.(like jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js in which i have to change from $ to $j)

So my question is can we rename $ in prototype.js to something else, so it will be easy.I am using prototype of version 1.5.1.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no - the some of the PrototypeJS modules (Array, Enumerable, RegExp, String, etc) depend on the `$()` function being available, and expect it to return an extended element instead of a jQuery collection.

However you can wrap the jQuery code in a immediately executed function to work around your problem.

for example

```
(function($){

    //jQuery code in here that uses $()


})(jQuery);
```

This is basically a Javascript closure that renames the `jQuery()` method to `$()` inside that context

Comment: Thanks Geek, but what about the plugins that internally use $(as a reference of jquery like jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js, jquery.dataTables.min.js). Do we have to change them manually if yes then if we are upgrading plugins  then we have to again do the rework. Can't we just go to prototype.js and change all the reference of $ to something else.

Comment: I've done that in the past where I wrapped the whole plugin in the function closure. Yes it does make it a little painful to update the plugin, but it does make it more portable. Maybe you can also submit a pull request to the author to wrap the plugin in the closure.

Comment: Actually i did that and its working fine but one problem is there. while calling $(selector).show() (for query). It gets called for prototype.js don't know how. I have changed all the reference of $ to $p in prototype.js.

Comment: I would need to see more source to figure out why its still going that route in that instance. I know sometimes jQuery will call the Prototype methods that are added to `Element` when jQuery is firing events, but this doesnt sound like the same problem.

Comment: Actually any properly written plugin already uses this wrapper.

Comment: @GeekNum88, can i remove some methods that jquery already have. Don't  know what i am doing is correct approach or not(replacing $ to $p in proptotype.js) .

Comment: @Bergi i am using jquery datatable pluging that gives aocolumn undefined after adding prototype.js otherwise it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

changing $ to $p causing some problem(like calling jquery hide or show function, prototype.js function gets called). So i what did to solve the conflict is to open a prototype.js related things in new tab and using jquery.noConflict().